# How do I structure MySQL tables where one field could contain multiple values (but might not)?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a web app which allows users to attend events and search for specific types of events.
Say, for instance, that these events are taking place in Hogwarts. The students have their own table where their studentID is held as a primary key, and this also contains which house they are a part of (of which there are 4), the subject they take, and which year of study they are in (e.g. 1 or 4 or 5, etc). The events can be for all students, specifically for 4th year students in the Ravenclaw house, or anywhere in between.

The events are held in an events table, which contains an eventID as the primary key, but I'm not sure how to hold the data for the house/year/subject it is aimed at. Obviously if an event were only aimed at 3rd year Hufflepuffs who take Potions, or something similarly specific, I could hold it within the same table. However, what if the event is for any year of Hufflepuffs (and not any Slytherins, etc)? Or if all students from all years, houses and subjects are eligible to attend? Will I need a table which holds all the years for each event and a separate table for which houses it's for and a further separate table for the subject it's aimed at?

Any advice or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two ways but you definitely need at least one more table for the associations. Either you want to be very specific, about the combinations possible or you want to do it generally, like: only third years, only hufflepuffs, then the combination of the two values will be only third year hufflepuffs.

What I am trying to say are these two options.

1) One table that holds rows with very specific details:Event ID and the explicit combinations of all possible options (Here you will have a lot of rows)

This would mean that the event can be associated with second and third year hufflepuffs, but only second year slytherins.

```
association_id event_id   year_id   house_id     subject_id
1              1           second    hufflepuff   potions
2              1           third     hufflepuff   potions
3              1           second    slytherin    potions
```

2) One table per property (here the disctinction is not as clear but you only have to create one row per property etc.

The following two tables could be used to store that all hufflepuffs and all slytherins that are in second or third year might attend

```
association_id event_id year_id
1              1        second
2              1        third

association_id event_id house_id
1              1        hufflepuff
2              1        slytherin
```

Does that answer your question or at least help you to find a solution?

Mybe if you can describe the target you are aiming at more closely one can find a solution suitable for your Problem together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I, for some reason, separated year, house and subject into separate tables thinking this would be a good idea, but I think the first example you gave me would be best for me. I'm not too bothered about efficiency but out of curiosity, would one be faster to return queries than the other by any noticeable difference?

Comment: To be fair I am not sure, sorry. It probably depends on the data you have and how the different properties are combined in your queries.